# hibernate.ddl.auto=update create DDL error CommandAcceptanceException

Tags: mysql, jpa

My environment: mysql8  springboot 2.1

Here is my question,**I want to use the jpa to create the table order**,but when I run the project,It shows the error message.

If I change the **@Table(name="order") to @Table(name="`order`")**,It works.
I'm not sure where is wrong? 
Thanks in advance

This is my entity.
[image: orderentity]

This is my jpa properties of spring config
[image]

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
create table order (
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
    create_time date not null,
    customer_id bigint not null,
    order_money decimal(19,2) not null,
    real_pay_money decimal(19,2) not null,
    serial_no varchar(20) not null,
    type smallint not null,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.trifail.order.OrderApplication.main(OrderApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        create_time date not' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` is reserved word in MySQL. It is needed to escape it using quotation marks

Comment: Oh... You are right...That's why when I change it to `order` it works.I spent 1 hour on this problem....It helps me a lot.Thanks